# Getting error invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*

Tags: programming, c, sketch, array, cpp

I have written this sketch, and I am trying to populate the array of wifi hotspots to  set the value in html select using javascript dynamically.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

const char* ap_ssid     = "ESP8266";
const char* ap_password = "0123456789";

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 8080
AsyncWebServer ap_server(8080);


const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html {
     font-family: Arial;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    h2 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    p { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    .units { font-size: 1.2rem; }
    .dht-labels{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      vertical-align:middle;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  var select = document.getElementById("wifi");
  hotspots = %wifi_networks%;
  for(index in hotspots) {
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(hotspots[index], index);
  }
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Connect to a Wifi Networks</h2>
  <p>
    <form action="#">
  <label for="wifi">Choose a hotspot to connect:</label>
  <select name="wifi" id="wifi">
    <option value="volvo">None</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="wifi">Enter password:</label>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type="rescan" value="Rescan">
  <input type="submit" value="Connect">
  </form>
  </p>
</body>

</script>
</html>)rawliteral";


void setup() {
  Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
  // Remove the password parameter, if you want the AP (Access Point) to be open
  WiFi.softAP(ap_ssid, ap_password);

  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);

  // Print ESP8266 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  ap_server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, getWifiHotspots());
  });

  // Start server
  ap_server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

But I am geting this error

```
    /Arduino/libraries/ESPAsyncWebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:243:10: error:   initializing argument 4 of 'void AsyncWebServerRequest::send_P(int, const String&, const uint8_t*, size_t, AwsTemplateProcessor)' [-fpermissive]

     void send_P(int code, const String& contentType, const uint8_t * content, size_t len, 
AwsTemplateProcessor callback=nullptr);
          ^

exit status 1
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Try to force the conversion in the function parameter: `send_P(200, "text/html", (uint8_t *)index_html, getWifiHotspots());`.

Answer (score 1):

In the library ESPAsyncWebServer.h are these two possible function variants defined

```
  void send_P(int code, const String& contentType, const uint8_t * content, size_t len, AwsTemplateProcessor callback=nullptr);
   void send_P(int code, const String& contentType, PGM_P content, AwsTemplateProcessor callback=nullptr);
```

So  when using

```
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(<YOUR HTML here>)rawliteral";
```

give the compiler the explicit instruction

```
ap_server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
  request->send_P(200, "text/html", (const uint8_t*) index_html, getWifiHotspots());
 });
```

The code compiles error free on ArduinoIDE 1.8.12/ESP8266 2.71/ NodeMCUv1 (as not having your definition of getWifiHotspots() I defined it as char)

Comment: I see, I am getting error because `index_html` is of `char` type and the `getWifiHotspots` returns array of `Strings`?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz No, as the error message clearly states, the argument is a `const char *`, and the function expects a `const uint8_t *`. -- BTW, actually you are programming C++, and the right cast is `static_cast<const uint8_t *>(...)`.